# Is there an improvement for this book section index extractor program?

Tags: python

I am trying to extract the section index from a file contains multiple lines of titles of a book.

Here is a sample

```
rawlines = '''
1 A C++ Primer 1
1.1 Basic C++ Programming Elements 2
1.1.1 A Simple C++ Program 2
'''
```

first, I split this into a list

```
raw_list = [y for y in (x.strip() for x in rawlines.splitlines()) if y]
```

then, I match each item in the list

```
section_index_list = []
for i in raw_list:
    a = re.findall('\d{1}\.\d{1}\.\d{1}',i)
    if len(a):
        section_index_list.append(a[0])
        continue
    a = re.findall('\d{1}\.\d{1}',i)
    if len(a):
        section_index_list.append(a[0])
        continue
    a = re.findall('\d{1}',i)
    if len(a):
        section_index_list.append(a[0])
        continue
```

now, `section_index_list` stores what I need

```
['1', '1.1', '1.1.1']
```

job is done but I think there may be improvement for this piece of code.
any idea?

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick

```
rawlines = '''
1 A C++ Primer 1
1.1 Basic C++ Programming Elements 2
1.1.1 A Simple C++ Program 2
'''

raw_list = [y for y in (x.strip() for x in rawlines.splitlines()) if y]
res = list(map(lambda i: i.split(' ')[0], raw_list))

# ['1', '1.1', '1.1.1']
```

Putting all into a function

```
def extractor(s):
    temp_list = [l for l in s.splitlines() if len(l)!=0]
    return list(map(lambda i: i.split(' ')[0], temp_list))

test = extractor(rawlines)
# ['1', '1.1', '1.1.1']
```

Comprehensive version

```
def extractor(s):
    return [l.split(' ')[0] for l in s.splitlines() if len(l)!=0]
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help. Its simple extraction I guess:

```
>>> rawlines = '''
... 1 A C++ Primer 1
... 1.1 Basic C++ Programming Elements 2
... 1.1.1 A Simple C++ Program 2
... '''
>>> [i.split(" ")[0] for i in rawlines.strip().split("\n")]
['1', '1.1', '1.1.1']
```